# How do I add new tab to the Contact Summary Page?

Tags: wordpress, hooks

I create a new plugin and I try to use hook for adding extra tab in the contents, my question is how to get $contactID?

```
add_action('civicrm_tabs', ' civitest_civicrm_tabs');

function civitest_civicrm_tabs( &$tabs, $contactID ) {

  // unset the contribition tab, i.e. remove it from the page
  unset( $tabs[1] );

  // let's add a new "contribution" tab with a different name and put it last
  // this is just a demo, in the real world, you would create a url which would
  // return an html snippet etc.
  $url = CRM_Utils_System::url( 'civicrm/contact/view/contribution',
                                "reset=1&snippet=1&force=1&cid=$contactID" );
  $tabs[] = array( 'id'    => 'mySupercoolTab',
                   'url'   => $url,
                   'title' => 'Contribution Tab Renamed',
                   'weight' => 300 );
}
```

Thank you

Nilda

Answer (score 4):

hook_civicrm_tabs is now deprecated and you should use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tabset.

Also note:

```
// $url should return in 4.4 and prior an HTML snippet e.g. '<div><p>....';
// in 4.5 and higher this needs to be encoded in json. E.g. json_encode(array('content' => <html form snippet as previously provided>));
// or CRM_Core_Page_AJAX::returnJsonResponse($content) where $content is the html code
// in the first cases you need to echo the return and then exit, if you use CRM_Core_Page method you do not need to worry about this.
```

Some example code:

```
function koba_civicrm_tabset($tabsetName, &$tabs, $context) {
  //check if the tab set is Event manage
  if ($tabsetName == 'civicrm/event/manage') {
    // Remove "Mond aan mond reclame" tab
    unset($tabs['friend']);
    // Remove "Location" tab: we use a contact subtype for location because it has better integration
    unset($tabs['location']);
    // Remove "Personal campaign pages": we don't use this
    unset($tabs['pcp']);


    // Add a Beheer Bijscholingen tab, a tab that shows a Drupal view
    if (!empty($context)) {
      $eventID = $context['event_id'];
      $url = CRM_Utils_System::url('admin/sitename/bijscholingen/json');
      $result = views_get_view_result('beheer_sitename_bijscholingen', 'page', $eventID);
      $count = count($result);
      $tabs['beheer'] = array(
          'weight' => 300,
          'count' => $count,
          'title' => ts('Beheer'),
          'link' => $url,
          'valid' => 1,
          'active' => 1,
          'current' => false,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The hook_civicrm_tabs is called by CiviCRM and provide the contactID argument. You don't need to use `add_action(...)` to call the hook.

Your example should work as is if you put it in a CiviCRM extension called civitest.

If you need help getting started with extension development, you can start with [CiviCRM Wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension)

Comment: This depends a bit on how the code is packaged. For a WordPress plugin, one would explicitly register the function using `add_action()`. For a Civi extension or Drupal module, there's no equivalent to `add_action()` because everything is based off naming conventions.